# Application never finishes starting in debug, possibly Redis?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, redis

I have an asp.net web application that is hosted in Azure and using a Redis cache to manage session storage. Every so often, the application will hang when debugging in localhost for no apparent reason.

Essentially, in Visual Studio, I'll hit the start button. A new web browser window will open like it's about to open the page, but instead it will simply load and load forever. If I try pausing the debug session, it seems to always land somewhere within the Redis dll, but I can't be sure where exactly.

No matter how many times I kill all processes and restart Visual Studio, this behavior will continue until I restart my computer. What could possibly be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redis was never designed to run on Windows, the version they make available is really only for testing purposes.

If you have issues with it hanging, it could be that it is miss-configured. [This question on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/708767/resdis-bgsave-hangs-forever-on-windows) may help.

Comment: My web.config file has it pointing at our actual Azure Redis cache, so I'm not running the redis locally (I think).